# error creating an Azure ML linked service in Azure Data Factory : The client xxx with object id xxx does not have authorization to perform action '

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-machine-learning-service

On Azure Data Factory I'm trying to create a linked Azure ML Service to be able to invoke a published model in ADF.

It gives me the following error :

> Request sent to Azure ML Service for operation 'validateWorkspace' failed with http status code 'Forbidden'. Error message from Azure ML Service: '{"error":{"code":"AuthorizationFailed","message":"The client XXX with object id XXX does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.MachineLearningServices/workspaces/read' over scope '../Microsoft.MachineLearningServices/workspaces/myworkspace' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials."}}'.

When I check on Azure ML Service workspace name **Acces Control IAM** ,
the related ADF has data factory contributor role on **This Resource** scope.

When I check on ADF **Acces Control IAM** ,
the related Azure ML Workspace has contributor role on **This Resource** scope.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A little late to this one, but perhaps it will help someone else.

I had this exact same issue and solved it by setting the ADF as Owner of the AML workspace.

```
az role assignment create --role "Owner" --assignee-object-id <adf-object-id> --scope /subscriptions/<subscription-id>/resourceGroups/<rg-name>/providers/Microsoft.MachineLearningServices/workspaces/<aml-workspace-name>
```

Or this can be done in the portal:

Navigate to your AML workspace -> Access Control (IAM) -> + Add -> Add role assignment.
Then add your data factory as the owner.

Answer (score 0):

In the DataFactory, you can test the connection to the Workspace.
Have you done this?

If this doesn't work, then re-establish the linked service in your DataFactory and make sure the keys are properly set.